# Prevent text from breaking and going to new line in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, arabic, arabic-support

I have arabic text the issue is it randomly breaks at single point and goes to new line even though the space is available around. Below is an example for reference.
[image]

All of the arabic text is saved as html definition of decimal character code on ASCII table.
So basically this:
[image]

Notice how in console the text is shown completely fine but not on the webapp.
Here's my implementation for the text:

```
child: AutoSizeText(
  functions.getArabicVerion(getJsonField(
     qaidaItem2Item,
       r'''$''',
    ).toString().replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0')),
    style: Theme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
    fontFamily: 'meQuran',
    fontSize: double.parse(textSizeValue),
    useGoogleFonts: false,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with flutter, that now has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you add u00A0 it will essentially add a space. You can replace it with an empty string instead

```
replaceAll(' ', '').replaceAll('\n', '');
```

And remove auto resize widget

Comment: that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you add the character codes here please?

Comment: Try replacing new line too. Edited my answer

Comment: Doesn't work with new lines either.
&#1605;&#1616;&#1605;&#1617;&#1614;

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of auto size text?

Comment: oh thanks, autotext was part part of the reason.